# Upload form with Dropzone, jQuery and php - no individual response while uploading multiple files

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, upload, dropzone.js

As stated, I have a problem with the response if I upload multiple files at once.
For example, I upload `a.jpg` and `b.jpg`.
In the next step, I upload `b.jpg` and `c.jpg`.
My PHP script checks the names for duplicity and finds one in `b.jpg` but as response, I got each images flagged with

> error - file already there.

I can't differ the responses individually.

I initialize my dropzone via jquery:

```
myDropZone = $("#dropzone").dropzone({
 autoProcessQueue: false,
 uploadMultiple: true,
 xx: xx

 init:function(){
     var self = this;
     // check error and some other states
     self.on("error", function (file, response) {
         console.log("error: "+file);
         console.log("error-response: "+response);
     }
     // set process
     $("#actions .start").click (function(file){
         self.processQueue();
     }
 }
});
```

I use `uploadMultiple` for multiple fileupload, I disabled the `autoprocess` and binded the function `processQueue()` to a button of my liking.
So far so good.

No I have my php-script processing the data. It should be called once because of the `uploadMultiple` parameter.

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    // resort array for easy processing
    for($i = 0 ;$i < count($_FILES['file']['name']) ; $i++) {
        $fileArrays[] = array_column ( $_FILES['file'], $i);
    }
    foreach($fileArrays as $file) {
        $upload = array();
        if(file_exists($file[0])) {
            $upload[] = "File already there.";
        }
        // some other validations...
    }
    if(empty($upload)) {
        //move_uploaded_file()
        http_response_code(200);
    } else {
        print_r($upload);
        http_response_code(404);
    }
```

But now all uploads get all responses, whether they are true or not.
For example, I upload `b.jpg` and `c.jpg`, where `b.jpg` already exists. Both images get the success icon.

Now I upload `d.jpg` and `c.jpg` (note the order), where `c.jpg` already exists and both images the the error

> File already there

[image]

Does anybody have the same problem with the response?
Maybe I'm doing the php-validation wrong?
Or do I have to handle the dropzone-event-parameter (success, etc.) in another way? I tried `successmultiple`, `completemultiple`, etc. but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

"Solved" it by switching from ProcessQueue to:

```
self.getQueuedFiles().forEach(function(element) {
    self.processFile(element);
});
```

Brougth some other problems with it but they were solvable.